# How to make site available offline using Laravel Mix Workbox

Tags: progressive-web-apps, laravel-mix, workbox-window

I have a Laravel Vue PWA using [Laravel Mix Workbox](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/workbox).

In webpack.mix.js I have:

```
mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .generateSW({
        additionalManifestEntries: [{url: 'index.php', revision: '1'}]
    })
```

Note here I have manually added `index.php` as an additional manifest entry. This is because the html contained in `index.php` is my [application shell](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell) and needs to be cached in order to make my application available offline.

In my main `app.js` I have:

```
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window'
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching'
import { registerRoute, NavigationRoute } from 'workbox-routing'

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

    const wb = new Workbox('/service-worker.js')

    precacheAndRoute([
        { url: '/index.php', revision: '383676' }
    ])

    const handler         = createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.php')
    const navigationRoute = new NavigationRoute(handler)
    registerRoute(navigationRoute)

    wb.register()
}
```

I'm using [Workbox Window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window) as it claims to make everything easier.

Note I'm calling `precacheAndRoute` here as otherwise I get the error `createHandlerBoundToURL('/index.php') was called, but that URL is not precached.` I don't understand why this is necessary as I can see that `index.php` is already in the array passed to `precacheAndRoute` in my `server-worker.js`.

I have tried using Workbox Window `messageSW` function instead passing `'CACHE_URLS'` with `index.php` but this didn't fix the error.

The aim of this bit of code is to register a navigation route so I can return specific response for all navigation requests as per [Google's documentation on navigation requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_navigation_route).

I can now view the site in Chrome, see the service worker is installed, but when I check "Offline" and reload the page I just get the message "No internet".

Looking at the network I can see the request to `/dashboard` is failing.

**How can I make my site work offline?**

And why isn't the service worker using the cached `index.php` to respond to the request?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: No, don't have a simple solution, or at least can't remember. Was definitely a challenge.